# Unable to get Listview to refresh from Database

Tags: android, database, listview, dynamic, refresh

No matter what I seem to try and do regarding this listview and trying to get it to dynamically update whenever I hit a button it doesn't work and always throws a NPE.

The code is below and I would really welcome an assistance.  I've tried requery and I've tried notifyDataSetChanged, but I'll be honest, this is only my second project and the 1st one that is using a database or listview and I'll struggling.

DatabaseHelper

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; 
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "reordermymeds.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Medicines";
public static final String C_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
public static final String C_MED_NAME = "med_name"; 
public static final String TABLE_NAME_SURG = "Surgeries";
public static final String SURGERY_NAME = "sName";
public static final String SURGERY_TEL = "sTel";
public static final String SURGERY_MAIL = "sMail";



public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sql = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, %s     TEXT)", TABLE_NAME, C_ID, C_MED_NAME);
    String sql_surg = String.format(
            "create table %s (%s int primary key, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
            TABLE_NAME_SURG, C_ID, SURGERY_NAME, SURGERY_TEL, SURGERY_MAIL);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);

    db.execSQL(sql);
    db.execSQL(sql_surg);



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME_SURG);
    this.onCreate(db);
}

}
```

and

Activity

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class pills extends ListActivity {

public static final String C_MED_NAME = "med_name";
public SimpleCursorAdapter ladapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pills);

    try {

            DatabaseHelper DBHelper= new DatabaseHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();


            Cursor cur = db.query("Medicines", null, null, null, null, null, null);
            startManagingCursor(cur);

            String [] columns = new String[] {C_MED_NAME};
            int [] to = new int[] {R.id.meditem};

            SimpleCursorAdapter ladapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.meditem, cur, columns, to);

            this.setListAdapter(ladapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    Button saveMed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pills_newmedsubmit);
    saveMed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final EditText newMed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pills_newmedtxtbox);

            if (newMed.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Please type the name of a new prescription item.";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
            }
            else
            {

                    String medName = newMed.getText().toString();

                    insertNewPrescriptionItem(medName);

                    EditText clearTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pills_newmedtxtbox);
                    clearTextBox.setText("");

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Saved";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();


            }

        setListAdapter(ladapter);
        ladapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    });}

    private void insertNewPrescriptionItem (String medName){

        DatabaseHelper DbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        SQLiteDatabase db = DbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(DatabaseHelper.C_MED_NAME, medName);

            db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper.C_MED_NAME, cv);
            db.close();
            }


}
```

and of course, last but not least, the stack trace.  I can see the line with the error, but every I have tried using Google just results in the same thing.  Can anyone show were I must be going stupidly wrong??

Stack Trace

```
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at com.asurya.reordmymeds.pills$1.onClick(pills.java:90)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-11 01:21:26.095: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 01:21:26.107: WARN/ActivityManager(110):   Force finishing activity com.asurya.reordmymeds/.pills
```

Oops.  It would have helped if I let you all know that rather than count them yourselves:)

The line of code which is causing the NPE is:

```
ladapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also, if I simply comment out this line, the app runs fine, but you have to refresh the Activity to see the updated data in the database.  Thanks all.

Comment: Oops.  It would have helped if I let you all know that rather than count them yourselves:)  The line of code which is causing the NPE is    ladapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  Also, if I simply comment out this line, the app runs fine, but you have to refresh the Activity to see the updated data in the database.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class pills extends ListActivity {

    public static final String C_MED_NAME = "med_name";
    public SimpleCursorAdapter ladapter;
    Context context;
    Cursor cur;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pills);
        context=this;
        try {

                DatabaseHelper DBHelper= new DatabaseHelper(this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();


                cur = db.query("Medicines", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                startManagingCursor(cur);

                String [] columns = new String[] {C_MED_NAME};
                int [] to = new int[] {R.id.meditem};

                ladapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.meditem, cur, columns, to);

                this.setListAdapter(ladapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        Button saveMed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pills_newmedsubmit);
        saveMed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final EditText newMed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pills_newmedtxtbox);

                if (newMed.getText().toString().equals("")) {

    //                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Please type the name of a new prescription item.";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                }
                else
                {

                        String medName = newMed.getText().toString();

                        insertNewPrescriptionItem(medName);

                        EditText clearTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pills_newmedtxtbox);
                        clearTextBox.setText("");

    //                  Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Saved";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();


                }

            refresh();

            }


        });}

        private void insertNewPrescriptionItem (String medName){

            DatabaseHelper DbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

            SQLiteDatabase db = DbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                cv.put(DatabaseHelper.C_MED_NAME, medName);

                db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper.C_MED_NAME, cv);
                db.close();
                }


    }
public void refresh(){
cur = db.query("Medicines", null, null, null, null, null, null);
ladapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

try this, i think your context is null thats why it is happening so

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help, it's the same error.  The Logcat is still showing the ladapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as the line that is causing the problem.

Comment: It's still the same I'm afraid.  I've seen other code example using a class which extends the BaseAdapter().  Is that something I would need as well as the other than the front page of the activity, these are the only two classes I have in my project?

Comment: OK, it's working now - but not quite.  Your changes to my code have certainly took care of the NPE (thanks for that) but it's not doing what I thought it would do, which is refresh the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set the adapter you dont need to do `.setListAdapter()`. Declare you adapter as global variable in your class (as you did at the beginning), and then just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` at point where there is change in the adapter data. If it doesnt work, try reinstantiating the adapter on and on, and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

In the try remove the type definition of the adapter, you already did `public SimpleCursorAdapter ladapter;` just feed it with data in the try.