# How to requery for a cursor now if requery is deprecated?

Tags: android, android-cursor

As per the title, if we used to call `cursor.requery()`, but it is now deprecated. How do you call this function now?

> This method is deprecated.
> Don't use this. Just request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes back.

So how does one request a new cursor and pass it back to the adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-initialize cursor when your any DML query execute.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019517/unable-to-get-listview-to-refresh-from-database/7020582#7020582).

Answer (score 2):

Just think about a block where you need to use cursor again and again. Populate it with the query. Work with it and then close before reusing

```
{
    Cursor c =//Populating cursor again
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
    }
    if (c != null) c.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) to manage your cursors. It will return a new Cursor as needed and you can use `swapCursor()` on the adapter to refresh the data.

Comment: You can use the compatibility library, it works with 1.6 and up. Or, if you don't care about Honeycomb, leave it as is.

Answer (score -1):

I used **ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**; this worked only on list (like ArrayList), when the listcontent changed.
Using databaseoutput, it doesn't work anymore. Therefore I took **cursor.requery();** which is not only depricated. It also works only, if database entries changed.

But now, I want to change my view (switch between birthdays and dates) by changing my settings in a database, so requery does not recognize it.

For all changes works (a little bit dirty): **this.onCreate(null);**