# Refresh listview content when there is an sqlite database change

Tags: android, sqlite

i'am getting my `Listview` data from an `sqlite` `database` like this

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();


    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.row_listview,  arrayList);
            setListAdapter(aa);
Cursor cursor8 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM test21", null);
            if(cursor8.getCount() == 0)
            {


                textView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }cursor8.close();




                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM test21", null);
                    //  Toast.makeText(myContext, ""+cursor.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst())

                    {
                        do {
                            arrayList.add(cursor.getString(3));




                           }
                        while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
```

When i click another button it remove all the data of the `sqlitedatabase`.

How can i `refresh` the content of the `listview` because there is now nothing. I  always need to go back in the `activity` each time :(

Comment: use a Loaders with cursorAdapter. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: reformat your code! it cannot be read...

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the notifyDataSetChanged() and call requery() on your Cursor. Here is a sample [project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants) demonstrating this.

Hope it will works for you.

Comment: yep but it says requery is depracted :(

Comment: again re-initialize cursor when your any DML query execute, can refer this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019517/unable-to-get-listview-to-refresh-from-database/7020582#7020582